# ¿Cómo hacer que los atajos de emmet funcionen en los .html.twig de visual studio code?

Tags: symfony2, twig, vscode, emmet

Ya tengo instalad `VS Code Twig Language 2` pero aparentement no funcionan los atajos de emmet.
he probado con:
`'div>*2'` por hacer una prueba y no funciona.

He probado con `"div.html>.twig"` como dice esta pagina:

https://community.c9.io/t/emmet-not-working-in-html-twig-templates/23087
y a pulsar dos veces tabulacion y nada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En las opciones de Visual Studio modifica el atributo `emmet.includeLanguages`:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {   
    "twig": "html"
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Funciona genial, solo aclarar que estamos hablando del archivo: /Code/User/settings.json . El mismo que se menciona un en el comentario de arriba.

Comment: Acede al archivo escribiendo en la consola: `$ code ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: O simplemente en el propio Visual Studio Code, en File > Preferences > Settings y en la barra de búsqueda escribes "emmet.includeLanguages"

Comment: Creo que mi opcion favorita es : 
ctrl + p > settings json

Answer (score 1):

Podrías forzar a que VSCode reconozca la extensión `.html.twig` como html puro, con lo cual tendrías acceso inmediato a emmet, hice una prueba y así me funcionó emmet. Si estás de acuerdo con esta opción tienes que entrar a `Preferences: Open Setting (JSON)` Con el comando `Ctrl + Shift + P`, una vez entras al archivo JSON buscas si tienes la propiedad `"files.associations"`, si la tienes le añades
`"*.html.twig": "html"`, sino la tienes añades la propiedad completa así:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html.twig": "html"
},
```

Comment: ¿Esto me quitaría los atajos de twig?

Comment: Los atajos de twig parece que no, pero si los fragmentos de códigos propios que he ligado al los tiwg.

Comment: Ademas muestra errores de sintaxis en algunos twig.

Comment: Claro, mi prpuesta iba enfocada a perder las funcionalidades de Twig, pero a ganar todas las de Emmet al "engañar" al vscode mostrándole que esa extensión era símplemente html. La dificultad acá es que twig no está actualmente registrado como un lenguaje oficial en vscode, por lo que no lo puedes vincular directamente con Emmet. Si logras vincularlo de forma "oficial" aunque sea en tu instancia de vscode podrás hacer la asociación con emmet.